# integrate function of a function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, numerical-integration, symbolic-integration

i am trying to integrate a power sum raised to power of 1.2.

The question is this *integrate (((t^1)+(t^2)+(t^3))^(1.2)) from 0 to 1, with respect to t.*

```
x=1:3
syms t
y=sum(t.^x)
fun=@(y) y^(1.2)
integral(fun,0,1)
```

Output as: Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

But I'm not trying to compute elementwise.

Any comment/insight would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What line is the error at? `y` or your `fun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, in your last line you refer to the generic `y` that has nothing to do with `y` you have specified before. so, instead of `fun` you need `fun(y)`. Then, since the output of your `fun` is symbolic expression, then you need to convert this expression to the function handle using `matlabFunction`. So, the final code would look like:

```
x=1:3
syms t
y=sum(t.^x)
fun=@(y) y^(1.2)
integral(matlabFunction(fun(y)),0,1)
```

Output:

```
1.1857
```

Hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing symbolic math (`syms` and `sum`) with a numeric function to evaluate the integral (`integarl`). While it is possible, it is typically not a good idea because you end up with the precision problems of a numeric solution and the bad performance of the symbolic math toolbox. If you want a numeric solution, do not use any function from the symbolic toolbox. If you want to solve it with the symbolic math toolbox, maybe getting a analytic result, use `int` from the symbolic toolbox.

To explain what happened in your case. `integral` evaluates your function for multiple y-values to calculate the integral, something like `fun([0,.5,1])`. Your function calculates y^1.2 which is not possible, you want the element-wise operation in this case.

A further problem is, that the first `y` you assign is unused. The `y` in the next line where you define `fun` is a new variable.

This answer does not contain a solution because I do not know if a symbolic or numeric solution is intended.